# Mscrm Dynamics SOAP Send Email From Template

Tags: email, soap, dynamics-crm

I try to create an email with an template email in ms dynamics crm 4 with soap.
I manage to create an simple email and to sent it without problem with soapui.
But when I try with an template email, it not work. here is the soap message.

```
 <web:Execute xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:web="http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/WebServices">
    <web:Request  xsi:type="SendEmailFromTemplate">
    <web:TemplateId>EA84AF18-FC9-E11-A165-005069A6DB2</web:TemplateId>
    <web:RegardingType>invoice</web:RegardingType>
      <web:RegardingId>1175670-102-E61-AB42-0050569A6DB</web:RegardingId>
          <web:Target xsi:type="TargetSendFromTemplateEmail">
           <web:Email>
             <activityid>4B165B0-851-611-A42-00505696DB2</activityid>
           </web:Email>
         </web:Target>
        </web:Request>
  </web:Execute>
```

I received this error :

```
<soap:Body><soap:Fault>
<faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
<faultstring>Server was unable to process request.</faultstring>
<detail><error>
<code>0x80040216</code>
<description>An unexpected error occurred.</description>
<type>Platform</type>
</error></detail></soap:Fault>
```

Thank for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a 4.0 org available, but I executed the message against my 2015 org and captured the request in Fiddler.  Here's what the request looked like:

```
<Execute xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services">
    <request i:type="c:SendEmailFromTemplateRequest" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts" xmlns:c="http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2011/Contracts" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <b:Parameters xmlns:d="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic">
            <b:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                <d:key>TemplateId</d:key>
                <d:value i:type="e:guid" xmlns:e="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</d:value>
            </b:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
            <b:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                <d:key>RegardingType</d:key>
                <d:value i:nil="true"/>
            </b:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
            <b:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                <d:key>RegardingId</d:key>
                <d:value i:type="e:guid" xmlns:e="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</d:value>
            </b:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
            <b:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                <d:key>Target</d:key>
                <d:value i:type="b:Entity">
                    <b:Attributes>
                        <b:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                            <d:key>activityid</d:key>
                            <d:value i:type="e:guid" xmlns:e="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</d:value>
                        </b:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                    </b:Attributes>
                    <b:EntityState i:nil="true"/>
                    <b:FormattedValues/>
                    <b:Id>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</b:Id>
                    <b:KeyAttributes xmlns:e="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/7.1/Contracts"/>
                    <b:LogicalName>email</b:LogicalName>
                    <b:RelatedEntities/>
                    <b:RowVersion i:nil="true"/>
                </d:value>
            </b:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
        </b:Parameters>
        <b:RequestId i:nil="true"/>
        <b:RequestName>SendEmailFromTemplate</b:RequestName>
    </request>
</Execute>
```

I'm not exactly sure off the top of my head how different the request would look against a 4.0 endpoint, but it still might help you figure out how to structure your request.